# How positions component on the bottom of my screen

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-layouts

```
super();
this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
this.addComponent(new TopBar());
this.addComponent(new MyList());
this.addComponent(new BottomBar()); // must be below
```

I tried to use `BorderLayout`, but it didn't help me.

[image]

`myList` is not always occupy the  all screen. But it is always located under `mylist`.

Sorry for simple question, I'm still beginner lwuit.

Comment: If my answer has helped to solve your problem, then please mark it as accepted to help the future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might not be setting the layout to appropriate container, try below code see if it suits your requirement.

```
    Button topBar = new Button("TopBar");
    List mylist = new List(new String[]{"Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"});
    Button bottomBar = new Button("BottomBar");

    Form form = new Form();
    Container contentPane = form.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPane.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH, topBar);
    contentPane.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, mylist);
    contentPane.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, bottomBar);
    contentPane.revalidate();

    form.show();
```

The above code you can interchangeably use it with Container.

PS: In order to run the above code make sure you set the Resources and Theme correct in your code. If you need help on this check the LWUITDemo jar file / project that is included in the downloaded LWUIT library zip file.